# Show the Gini Coefficient is Quasiconvex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The Gini-coefficient is defined as
$$ G(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \left( \frac{i}{n} - \sum_{j=1}^{i} \frac{x_{(j)}}{\mathbb{1}^{T}x}\right), $$ where $x_{i} $ is nonnegative numbers with positive sum. $x_{(j)}$ denotes the j-th smallest number among $\{ x_1,x_2, ..,x_n \}$.

Show that the Gini coefficient is quasiconvex.

My approach:

Rewrite the sum as

$$ G(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{i}{n} - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{i} \frac{x_{(j)}}{\mathbb{1}^{T}x}. $$

We can rewrite this as

$$ b - \frac{c^Tx}{\mathbb{1}^Tx},$$

where $b = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{i}{n}$ and $c_i$ is the number of times $x_i$ is counted. Noting that G(x) is invariant to permutations we can assume that $x_1 \leq x_2,...,\leq x_{n-1} \leq x_n$ and then $c = (n,n-1,...,1)^T.$

Looking at the $\alpha$-sublevel set we have

$$S_{\alpha} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}, \mathbb{1}^{T}x > 0: G(x) \leq \alpha \} =$$
$$ \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}, \mathbb{1}^{T}x > 0: b - \frac{c^Tx}{\mathbb{1}^{T}x} \leq \alpha \} = $$
$$ \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}, \mathbb{1}^{T}x > 0: ((b-\alpha)\mathbb{1}  -c)^Tx  \leq 0 \}. $$

which is an intersection of three convex sets, hence convex.

Is this correct?

Comment: I'm afraid not. We cannot, in fact, assume that $x_1\leq x_2\leq\dots\leq x_n$ and $c=(n,n-1,\dots,n)$, because then that value of $c$ only applies *in the region where that inequality is true*. You're trying to prove quasiconvexity for all $x$. What happens right on the boundary between $x$ is naturally ordered that way and when it is not?

Comment: Put another way, $c$ is actually a function of $x$ in your expressions for $S_\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks I see your point. I guess the argument holds for any restriction of the domain when $x$ has a certain order, then we can find a constant $c$. However, to make it valid for all $x$  one needs to show that the union of all sublevel sets over all permutations are convex, which might not be easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_i(x) = \sum_{j=1}^i x_{(j)}$. This is a *concave* function of $x$. To prove it, define
$$S_{(i)}\triangleq \{s\in\{0,1\}^n\,|\,\textstyle\sum_j s_j = i\}$$
In other words, $S_{(i)}$ is the set of all $\{0,1\}$ vectors with exactly $i$ ones. Then
$$f_i(x) = \inf_{s\in S_{(i)}} s^Tx.$$
Because $f_i(x)$ is the pointwise infimum of affine functions, it is concave. (See, for instance, $\S3.2.3$ of *Convex Optimization* by Boyd & Vandenberghe.)

Now we can write $G(x)$ as follows:
$$G(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{n}-\frac{f_i(x)}{1^Tx}$$
And the sublevel set inequality becomes
$$
G(x) \leq \alpha \quad
\Longleftrightarrow\quad \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{n}(1^Tx)-f_i(x) \leq \alpha (1^Tx)$$
The left-hand side is convex, the right-hand side is affine, so the inequality describes a convex set. Hence the sublevel set is convex, and $G(x)$ is quasiconvex.

Comment: $f_i(x) = \sum_{j=1}^i x_{(j)}$ instead of $f_i(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n x_{(j)}$.

Comment: Couldn't you use this same argument to say $G(x) \geq \alpha$ are convex sets, thereby proving the function quasiconcave? Is this function quasilinear?